# I want to add the meaning of an error to the output of a bash script

Tags: bash, loops, awk, printf, echo

I have a source file populated with lines like these ones.

```
e9999=$"First named error has occurred"
e1000=$"Second named error has occurred"
e0000=$"Another named error has occurred"
```

---

I have a script, which ends up with a output of lines like these (the script is multiple greps into some sed and then further greps).

```
Dec 03 22:15:49      uniqid c5bb3ed1d2110203e2850998f1008e92   IP 0.0.0.0   email@email.fqdn StatusCode: 1000
Dec 04 07:53:12      uniqid 476ceb443a552012a1dd1e754d279018   IP 255.255.255.255   email@email.fqdn StatusCode: 9999
Dec 04 10:51:08      uniqid 4c27a6e016e8b5c0a659274d20c86e0c   IP 192.168.0.1   email@email.fqdn StatusCode: 0000
```

---

I wish to ADD the meaning of each lines'statuscode' to the end of the output.

**example:**

```
Dec 03 22:15:49      uniqid c5bb3ed1d2110203e2850998f1008e92   IP 0.0.0.0   email@email.fqdn StatusCode: 1000 Second named error has occurred
Dec 04 07:53:12      uniqid 476ceb443a552012a1dd1e754d279018   IP 255.255.255.255   email@email.fqdn StatusCode: 9999 First named error has occurred
Dec 04 10:51:08 uniqid 4c27a6e016e8b5c0a659274d20c86e0c IP 192.168.0.1 email@email.fqdn StatusCode: 0000 Another named error has occured
```

The amount of lines in the original result can vastly vary

The error codes can vastly vary (but always 4 digits) and all are in the source file

The order of error codes can vary (unless a sort of the row will make it easier).

### This is all done through RHEL bash

** Sample input:**

Dec 05 19:20:46 app [debug] [session 75b49d52fdd572752c2848f9992cb838] [IP 255.255.255.255] Comms: Message: company_PassDelivery_Test_app18b4e79f-ee3c-4a15-91f0-f97edb15478cPassDelivery_app4d82fb84-bffb-4b48-aea1-98a60236fd48https://transp1..net/s2s/default.asp?id=3578ef0a3bbf105c08d533699efb9f2c891fc4ea2019-12-05T19:20:45ZCallPlaced7000
Dec 05 19:20:46 app [debug] [session 75b49d52fdd572752c2848f9992cb838] [IP 255.255.255.255] reg_phase1_info_request.p:  call in progress for email@e.com StatusCode: 7000
Dec 05 19:20:56 app [debug] [session 75b49d52fdd572752c2848f9992cb838] [IP 255.255.255.255] Comms: Message: 4d82fb84-bffb-4b48-aea1-98a60236fd48https://transp1..net/s2s/default.asp?id=3578ef0a3bbf105c08d533699efb9f2c891fc4ea2019-12-05T19:20:56Z7000
Dec 05 19:20:56 app [debug] [session 75b49d52fdd572752c2848f9992cb838] [IP 255.255.255.255] reg_phase1_info_request.p:  call in progress for email@e.com StatusCode: 3340
Dec 05 19:21:06 app [debug] [session 75b49d52fdd572752c2848f9992cb838] [IP 255.255.255.255] Comms: Message: 4d82fb84-bffb-4b48-aea1-98a60236fd48https://transp1..net/s2s/default.asp?id=3578ef0a3bbf105c08d533699efb9f2c891fc4ea2019-12-05T19:21:06Z7000
Dec 05 19:21:06 app [debug] [session 75b49d52fdd572752c2848f9992cb838] [IP 255.255.255.255] reg_phase1_info_request.p:  call in progress for email@e.com StatusCode: 3130
Dec 05 19:26:28 app [debug] [session 75b49d52fdd572752c2848f9992cb838] [IP 255.255.255.255] Comms: Message: company_PassDelivery_Test_app18b4e79f-ee3c-4a15-91f0-f97edb15478cPassDelivery_app4d82fb84-bffb-4b48-aea1-98a60236fd48https://transp1..net/s2s/default.asp?id=3578ef0a3bbf105c08d533699efb9f2c891fc4ea2019-12-05T19:26:28ZPhoneSessionDeliver3370
Dec 05 19:26:28 app [debug] [session 75b49d52fdd572752c2848f9992cb838] [IP 255.255.255.255] reg_phase1_info_request.p:  status unknown for email@e.com StatusCode: 3370
Dec 05 19:26:28 app [debug] [session 75b49d52fdd572752c2848f9992cb838] [IP 255.255.255.255] reg_phase1_info_request.p:  call end, msg type:result. StatusCode: 3013

** Sample of code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/ondemandscripts/errorcodes
today=$(date "+%b %d")
yesterday=$(date -d "1 day ago" "+%b %d")
echo -e "\nChecking "/opt/app/app/logs/PHP_Debug_Log" for  errors and users email address"
echo -e "\n"


if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
        echo -e "Designed for app\nUsage options:\n$0 all\n$0 today\n$0 yesterday\n$0 alluniq\n$0 todayuniq\n$0 yesterdayuniq\n"
                        exit 1;
                        fi
                        if [ $1 = "all" ]; then
                        grep -i 'statusCode' /opt/app/app/logs/PHP_Debug_Log | grep '1010\|1020\|2120\|2140\|2142\|2160\|2510\|2520\|2530\|2540\|2560\|3101\|3102\|3103\|3104\|3110\|3111\|3118\|3120\|3130\|3150\|3180\|3210\|3220\|3230\|3240\|3250\|3320\|3325\|3330\|3340\|3350\|3360\|3420\|3450\|3510\|3520\|3610\|3612\|3614\|3620\|3622\|3630\|3650\|3657\|3660\|3662' | sed 's/Comms.*<status>/  /' | sed 's/<\/statusCode>.*/ /' | sed 's/debug//'| sed 's/app//'| sed 's/>/ /' | sed 's/</ /' | sed 's/]/ /g' | sed 's/\[/ /g' | sed 's/reg_phase1.*result./ /' | sed 's/reg_phase1.*for / /' | grep -v "StatusCode: 7000" | grep 'email.com'

else
                               echo -e "Designed for app\nUsage options:\n$0 all\n$0 today\n$0 yesterday\n$0 alluniq\n$0 todayuniq\n$0 yesterdayuniq\n"

                                        fi
```

Comment: This is not at all clear. Please edit your question with 3 important thing. 1st-sample of input, 2- sample of output and 3rd- your efforts which you have put in order to solve your  own problem, please do edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: Where is your code to solve the problem, where are your problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on question, volume is (very) large, may rows, etc. This implies that scripting engines is needed here (awk, Perl, Python, ...). The logic is the same either way

- Preload the lookup table for error codes
- For each line:

  - Lookup the error code from column 10
  - Append error test to he line

With `awk`, assuming the lookup table is in errors.txt

```
awk -v LOOKUP=lookup.txt '
BEGIN {
   # Read the errors.txt file into array x, using custom  FS
   FS="=\\$"
   while ( (getline < LOOKUP) > 0 ) { x[$1] = substr($2, 2, length($2)-2) }
   # Restore FS
   FS=" "
}
{
   print $0, x["e" $10] ;
} 
' data.txt
```

Comment: @EdMorton Can you share the specific input that will throw getline into a loop in this case ? The usage above in described as `appropriate solution` in the 'Application' section, case C.

Comment: @EdMorton Good point. I've updated the answer. Somehow, I've missed this paragraph in the awk man, and assumed 0/1 result.

Comment: thanks, finally got time to add this in and its working as needed